# Make list auto stretch to container width

Tags: html, css

I have a list like this:

```css
.header-top {
  margin-bottom: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */
}
.nav{
    padding: 0;
}
.top-nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li div{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
    box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
}
.top-nav ul{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

}
.top-nav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin: 0 0.3em;
 color:#363636;
 font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="header-top ">
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="top-nav" id="nav1">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Company</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Enterns</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Partner</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Sales</a></div></li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Network</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Club</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Case study</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Public Service</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Donation</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Brand</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">LIBRARY</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">BOOKS</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">OTHERS</a></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

It's a menu. I want it to break line if it's overflow so I set display to `<li>` inline-block. It's works but I want every line to stretch full with to it's container. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flexbox` like this might be an option

Rule changed:

```
.top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.top-nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
}
```

And with `white-space: nowrap;` on the anchor, its text won't break line and `text-align: center` to center the text

Sample snippet

```css
.header-top {
  margin-bottom: 0.625em; /* 10/16 */
}
.nav{
    padding: 0;
}
.top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.top-nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
}
.top-nav ul li div{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
    box-shadow: 0.0625em 0.0625em 0.0625em #000000; /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 1/16 */
}
.top-nav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin: 0 0.3em;
 color:#363636;
 font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="header-top ">
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="top-nav" id="nav1">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Company</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Enterns</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Partner</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">For Sales</a></div></li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Network</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Club</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Case study</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Public Service</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Donation</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">Brand</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">LIBRARY</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">BOOKS</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div><a href="#">OTHERS</a></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```